# NameError: name 'argv' is not defined

Tags: python, google-api, python-3.4, argv

I am trying to make a Google API call and am getting an error with the beginning of the code found here:

```
import os

import argparse
import sys

from apiclient import sample_tools
from oauth2client import client

# Declare command-line flags.
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
argparser.add_argument(
    'profile_id', type=int,
    help='The ID of the profile to look up campaigns for')



  # Authenticate and construct service.
service, flags = sample_tools.init(
    argv[1:], 'dfareporting', 'v2.1', __doc__, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname("__file__")), parents=[argparser],
    scope=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfareporting',
           'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dfatrafficking'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)
```

However, the sample_tools.init function is not returning the service and flags object. I think I have isolated it to the argv argument a

```
NameError: name 'argv' is not defined
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: I think you need `sys.argv`?

Answer (score 10):

You are missing `sys`:

```
sys.argv[1:]
```

You either need to `from sys import argv` and use `argv` everywhere or `import sys` as you have and use `sys.argv`. I also don't see a `main` function anywhere so `main(sys.argv)` is also going to cause a NameError

Comment: Oh yes! I left it out in the paste but def main(argv):  came before service,flags =  . I tried all of those suggestions and I am still not able to get that function to work - but it does appear that argv is now defined as ['']  - if that is correct. Any other ideas would be appreciated!!!

Comment: How is it not working? Are you passing args to the script?